# How to obtain the number of Markov Chain transitions in a simulation?

Tags: markov-chains

I would like to obtain the number of transitions from each state in a Markov Chain simulation to other states, including back to itself so I can compare the simulation results to the transition matrix. I’m fairly new to Markov Analysis so please be gentle. From the help we have this relatively simple example involving weather.

```
weather = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0.7, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.6}}];
Graph[weather, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "rain", 2 -> "no rain"}, 
VertexSize -> Small, 
EdgeLabels -> 
With[{sm = MarkovProcessProperties[weather, "TransitionMatrix"]}, 
Flatten@Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

The transition matrix is obtained by

```
transitionmatrix = 
MarkovProcessProperties[weather, "TransitionMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

Now I simulate and plot 1000 days of behavior.

```
days = 1000;
data = RandomFunction[weather, {1, days}]
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, 2}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, days + 200}, {0, 2.5}}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Weather Condition"}, 
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {1, 2}, None, None}, 
PlotLabel -> "Simulation Results", 
Epilog -> {Text["Rain", {days + 100, 1}], 
Text["No Rain", {days + 100, 2}]}]
```

[image]

So far, so good (I think).
I can also determine the number of times we arrived in a state of rain (State 1) or in a state of no rain (State 2)

```
rainstates = Count[data["PathStates"], 1]
norainstates = Count[data["PathStates"], 2]
```

But from the simulation data, how can I determine

a) the number of times we arrived to State 1 from State 1 ?

b) the number of times we arrived to State 1 from State 2 ?

c) the number of times we arrived to State 2 from State 1 ?

d) the number of times we arrived to State 2 from State 2 ?

Comment: `Tally@Partition[data["Path"][[All, 2]], 2, 1]`?

Comment: @belisarius Thank you, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to remove the question from the unanswered queue:

You can get the number of transitions with

```
r = Tally@Partition[data["Path"][[All, 2]], 2, 1]
(*
{{{1, 1}, 387}, {{1, 2}, 172}, {{2, 1}, 171}, {{2, 2}, 269}}
*)
```

And get a visual representation with:

```
g1 = g;(*Your Graph*)
(PropertyValue[{g1, DirectedEdge @@ #[[1]]}, EdgeStyle] = 
                                 Thickness[.05 #[[2]]/Tr@r[[All, 2]]];
(PropertyValue[{g1, DirectedEdge @@ #[[1]]}, EdgeLabels] = 
                                 Style[#[[2]], Black, 18, Background -> Yellow])) & /@ r;
g1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]